# Replacement for cvGetSize() in OpenCV4?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently porting some legacy, OpenCV v1/v2 code and stumble upon following problem:

```
cv::Mat           *gray_image;
    
gray_image=ocvMatFromBin(bin,false);
...

cv::calibrateCamera(object_points,image_points,cvGetSize(gray_image),
                        intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs,
                        NULL,NULL,
                        CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO);
```

Here the compiler complains about `cvGetSize(gray_image)`, it seems `cvGetSize()` does not exist any more in OpenCV4. So what is the replacement for it? `cv::Size(gray_image)` does not do the job...

Thanks!

Comment: Try `gray_image->size()`.

Comment: @wohlstad does not seem to do the job: "error: no matching function for call to ‘calibrateCamera(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, NULL, NULL, cv::<unnamed enum>)" gray_image->size() does not return a cv::Size?

Comment: It actually returns a `MatSize` which is convertible to `cv::Size`. Try to assign to a variable: `cv::Size sz = gray_image->size();`.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper: cv::Mat::size is a data member of type `MatSize`. `MatSize` has an `operator()` that returns a `cv::Size`. Links: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a146f8e8dda07d1365a575ab83d9828d1, https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/df/d63/structcv_1_1MatSize.html.

Comment: @wohlstad OK, but I don't get it. When "size" is a member and when "size" has an operator "()" that returns what I need, the call should be size() - right? But this is exactly what causes the second compile error I see...

Comment: Yes. Does it work when you assign it to a local cv::Size variable (`cv::Size sz = gray_image->size();`)?

Comment: I've amended your question to clarify: this is a mix of opencv v2 (C++ API) and v1 (C API) code. and it's using pointers when that is wrong to do. cv::Mat behave like smart pointers. remove the usage of the pointer. -- what is `bin`?